# Use JMeter to test changing REST Service, JsonExtractor?

Tags: rest, jmeter, automated-tests

I am trying to test a REST service with JMeter (unsuccessfully). The REST service has some kind of security verification that disorders its callback order each time a request is made. To test the REST service, its mandatory to fill the 'IDTokenN' callbacks with its related values 'ValueN' as follows:

1st request:

```
{
"header": "Test",
"callbacks": [
    {
      "type": "NameCallback",
      "output": [
        {
          "name": "prompt",
          "value": "Callback A"
        }
      ],
      "input": [
        {
          "name": "IDToken1",
          "value": "ValueA"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "NameCallback",
      "output": [
        {
          "name": "prompt",
          "value": "Callback B"
        }
      ],
      "input": [
        {
          "name": "IDToken2",
          "value": "ValueB"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "NameCallback",
      "output": [
        {
          "name": "prompt",
          "value": "Callback C"
        }
      ],
      "input": [
        {
          "name": "IDToken3",
          "value": "ValueC"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

2nd request (B and C switch places, while A maintains its position) resulting in IDTokenN change its values to match the new order (now IDToken2 is "ValueC" and IDToken3 is "ValueB"):

```
{
"header": "Test",
"callbacks": [
    {
      "type": "NameCallback",
      "output": [
        {
          "name": "prompt",
          "value": "Callback A"
        }
      ],
      "input": [
        {
          "name": "IDToken1",
          "value": "ValueA"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "NameCallback",
      "output": [
        {
          "name": "prompt",
          "value": "Callback C"
        }
      ],
      "input": [
        {
          "name": "IDToken2",
          "value": "ValueC"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "NameCallback",
      "output": [
        {
          "name": "prompt",
          "value": "Callback B"
        }
      ],
      "input": [
        {
          "name": "IDToken3",
          "value": "ValueB"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

In successive requests, the order may (or may not) vary. I guess it should be accomplished with some sort of combination of JSON Extractors and CSV data sets (where I could find the relation of Callbacks - Answer) but I can't do it. Can anyone help me?

Thanks and sorry for the long post!

Kind regards,